# How many matrices in $M_n(\mathbb{F}_q)$ are nilpotent?

Tags: combinatorics, matrices

I have strong computational evidence to think that the answer is $q^{n(n-1)}$, although a proof eludes me.  Any ideas?

Comment: An idea I haven't fleshed out: a matrix $A$ is nilpotent if and only if $\operatorname{tr}(A^i) = 0$ for $i = 1, \dots, n$.  These are $n$, hopefully independent equations on a space of dimension $q^{n^2}$, voila.

Comment: @RyanReich I was staring at a similar statement on wikipedia, where it said that that characterization of nilpotentce only holds for "sufficiently large characteristic," which they didn't elaborate on. Do you happen to know the limitation?

Comment: @rschwieb: We need that $n!$ is invertible in order to use Newton's identities (this is also explained at Wikipedia).

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Great. Consider sharpening the statement in the middle of [the paragraph I was looking at](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nilpotent_matrix#Characterization) with an appropriate pointer or explanation so that other readers don't have to sift through an entire article as you bothered doing.

Comment: @RyanReich Replace $\mathrm{Tr}(A^i)$ with the coefficient of $x^i$ in the characteristic polynomial of $i$, and now you get a statement which is right in every characteristic. But that doesn't help explain why these equations should be independent.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a nice proof based on the two following lemmas. Let $V$ be a vector space of dimension $n$.

> **Lemma 1 (Fitting).** For all $u \in \mathcal{L}(V)$, there exists a unique decomposition $V=W_N \oplus W_I$ such that :
>
> - $u(W_N) \subset W_N$ and $u_{|_{W_N}}$ is nilpotent,
> - $u(W_I) \subset W_I$ and $u_{|_{W_I}}$ is inversible.

*Sketch of proof.* This a very special case of the Jordan normal form theorem.

> **Lemma 2.** For all $k \leq n$ there is a one-to-one correspondence between  the decompositions $W_1 \oplus W_2$ of $V$ with $\dim W_1=n-\dim W_2 = k$ and the quotient $$GL(n)/(GL(k)\times GL(n-k)).$$

*Sketch of proof.* Consider the natural group action of $GL(n)$ on the set of such decompositions.

---

Let $N_k$ denote the number of nilpotent matrices in $M_k(\Bbb F_q)$. Using the two lemmas, we see that
$$
q^{n^2} = \#M_n(\Bbb F_q) = \sum_{k=0}^n (N_k\cdot\#GL_{n-k})\cdot\dfrac{\#GL_n}{\#GL_k\cdot \#GL_{n-k}} = \#GL_n\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{N_k}{\#GL_k}
$$
which yields for all $n \geq 2$,
$$\dfrac{N_n}{\#GL_n(\Bbb F_q)} = \dfrac{q^{n^2}}{\#GL_n(\Bbb F_q)} - \dfrac{q^{(n-1)^2}}{\#GL_{n-1}(\Bbb F_q)}.$$
The result follows after simplification using the well-known fact that $$\#GL_k(\Bbb F_q) = (q^k-1)(q^k-q)\dots(q^k-q^{k-1}).$$

Comment: Don't you mean $\# \mathrm{GL}_{n-k}(\mathbb{F}_q)$ in the sum? I also don't understand $\# \mathrm{GL}_k(\mathbb{F}_q)$ in the denominator.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg: Actually the sum is $\sum_{k=0}^n(N_k\cdot\#GL_{n-k})\cdot\dfrac{\#GL_n}{\#GL_k\cdot \#GL_{n-k}}$. The second part is the number of couples $(V,W)$ of subspaces with $V\oplus W= \Bbb F_q^n$ and $\dim V = k$.

Comment: Ah, yes. Thank you!

Comment: The edit makes it very clear. Great answer! I wonder if there is a more direct proof which enumerates the nilpotent matrices.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg: The proof given in this [paper of Gerstenhaber](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ijm/1255629831) might be more explicit. You can also check the original proof of Fine and Herstein.

Comment: For the Lemma of Fitting you don't need Jordan normal form (which works only for alg.cl. fields anyway). See http://planetmath.org/fittingslemma for a complete and easy proof.

Comment: I really like your proof, it is more simple than the ones by Gerstenhaber, Fine-Herstein and Reiner. Back in the 50s this would have been worth a publication ...

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg: I'm not the author of this proof. It is a slight modification of the argument given in the paper (in french) by DE SEGUINS PAZZIS, Clément. *Dénombrements matriciels sur des corps finis*. RMS: Revue de la filière mathématiques, 2006, vol. 116, no 4.