# How many commuting pairs of unitriangular matrices are there in $GL_{n}(F_{p})$?

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, matrices, group-theory, finite-fields

I've been doing some work counting commuting pairs of unitriangular
matrices over $GL_{n}(F_{p})$.  So far, I believe that for $n=2$,
there are $p^2$ such pairs, and for $n=3$ there are $p^5+p^4-p^3$
such pairs.  Can anybody recognize these polynomials, generalize to
arbitrary $n<p$?

Recall that unitriangular matrices are upper-triangular matrices of
having entries of $1$ on the diagonal.

Any help would be appreciated so much. Thank you all.

Comment: [Related](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/343838)

Comment: This sounds really hard. The number of pairs of commuting elements in a group $G$ is $|G| c(G)$ where $c(G)$ is the number of conjugacy classes of $G$, and describing conjugacy classes in the unipotent group is hard.